# Have div change background postion on Hover and while Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have my **HTML** & **CSS** below.

I have a `div` with a `span` inside. Everything is lined up under the default home.

I want when I move the mouse over `About(id=Hover2)` it moves the `div (id=divHolder)` to the correct background position listed below. Also if I click `About`.

The correct background position of that div is active.

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="divHolder">
        <span id="highlight"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a id="Hover1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Hover2" href="About.aspx">About</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Hover3" href="">Profile</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Hover4" href="">News</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Hover5" href="">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  #divHolder {
    height: 62px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    width: 505px;

  }
 #highlight {
    background: url("/Styles/background-highlight.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 124px;
 }

  #divHolder.Hover1 {background-position:0px 0px} 
  #divHolder.Hover2 {background-position:0px 80px}
  #divHolder.Hover3 {background-position:0px 160px}
  #divHolder.Hover4 {background-position:0px 240px}
  #divHolder.Hover5 {background-position:0px 320px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xgkHH/

This is the jQuery I had to use:

```
$("#nav li").on("mouseenter",function() {
    classtoadd = $(this).children("a").attr("id");
    $("#highlight").addClass(classtoadd);
});
$("#nav li").on("mouseleave",function() {
    // remove all classes.
    $("#highlight").removeClass();
});
```

I didn't have to change your HTML at all, but here's what I did to your CSS:

```
#highlight.Hover1 {background-position:0px 0px;} 
  #highlight.Hover2 {background-position:0px 80px;}
  #highlight.Hover3 {background-position:0px 160px;}
  #highlight.Hover4 {background-position:0px 240px;}
  #highlight.Hover5 {background-position:0px 320px;}
```

Comment: This works, i just had the height and width of background position backwards. Now i just have to figure out alignment bc the picture is not matching up to the li, Thanks!

Comment: so this will add class on hover but how about while the link is active how can i add a class the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you can actually hover the element.  Using your code, it looks like the span covers some of the links which prevented hovering.

```
  $('#Hover2').hover(
    function(){
      $('#divHolder').addClass('Hover2');
    }, 
    function(){
      $('#divHolder').removeClass('Hover2');
    }
  );

$('#Hover2').on('click', function(){
    $('#divHolder').addClass('Hover2');//or whatever you want to do on click
});
```